# Swiper V7 React, lots of parameters not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, swiper.js

The following is my code:

I am trying to run through the docs of the Swiper library.

```
import React from "react";

// Direct React component imports
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react/swiper-react.js";
// Core modules imports are same as usual
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, EffectFade, Lazy } from "swiper";

// Styles must use direct files imports
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css"; // core Swiper
import "swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.min.css"; // Navigation module
import "swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.min.css"; // Pagination module
import "swiper/modules/scrollbar/scrollbar.min.css"; // Pagination module
import "swiper/modules/effect-fade/effect-fade.min.css";
import "swiper/modules/lazy/lazy.min.css";

export default function Scratchpad() {
  return (
    <Swiper
      modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, EffectFade, Lazy]}
      spaceBetween={10}
      slidesPerView={1}
      centeredSlides={"true"}
      direction={"vertical"}
      navigation
      effect="fade"
      // lazy
      // scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
      pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src={`https://picsum.photos/seed/${Math.random()}/200`} alt="" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src={`https://picsum.photos/seed/${Math.random()}/200`} alt="" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src={`https://picsum.photos/seed/${Math.random()}/200`} alt="" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src={`https://picsum.photos/seed/${Math.random()}/200`} alt="" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src={`https://picsum.photos/seed/${Math.random()}/200`} alt="" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src={`https://picsum.photos/seed/${Math.random()}/200`} alt="" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src={`https://picsum.photos/seed/${Math.random()}/200`} alt="" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src={`https://picsum.photos/seed/${Math.random()}/200`} alt="" />
      </SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
  );
}
```

Some elements work and others don't.

fade works
pagination works
scrollbar doesn't
direction doesn't

Does anyone have any ideas why?
I have tried all sorts of import methods and gone through the docs, but can't understand why some things work and others don't, even when implemented in the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:

So it seems like a lot has to do with the containers looking to be a certain size.

This is tricky to find in the docs, I'm still looking 
Found something here: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3691

Seems like if you set the container size to a fixed height it will work.